# 404 Not Found / nginx on php deploy to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Trying to do the [Google php "Bookshelf" tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore), and everything works fine locally. But when I deploy it to my Google Cloud Platform and try to browse to it, I get a "404 Not Found / nginx" error.

Here is the log file from the deployment:

```
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/nginx.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + cat
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + cat
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 08:50:31 default[20160709t034615]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,005 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,005 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,005 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,805 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 13
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,806 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 14
2016-07-09 08:50:32 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:32,807 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 15
2016-07-09 08:50:33 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:33,980 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:50:33 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:33,980 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:50:33 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 08:50:33,981 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 08:51:43 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:43,563 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-07-09 08:51:43 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:43,564 INFO waiting for cron, nginx, php-fpm to die
2016-07-09 08:51:43 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:43,564 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-07-09 08:51:43 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:43,567 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2016-07-09 08:51:44 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:44,472 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-07-09 08:51:44 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:44,474 INFO waiting for cron, nginx, php-fpm to die
2016-07-09 08:51:44 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:44,474 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-07-09 08:51:44 default[20160709t030800]  2016-07-09 08:51:44,478 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:29,498 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:29,498 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:29,500 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:29,500 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_INCLUDE=/app/nginx-app.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_INCLUDE=/app/nginx-app.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx-app.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx-app.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + cat
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + cat
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 09:23:29 default[20160709t041818]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 09:23:30 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:30,501 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 12
2016-07-09 09:23:30 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:30,503 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 13
2016-07-09 09:23:30 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:30,507 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 14
2016-07-09 09:23:31 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:31,621 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:23:31 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:31,621 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:23:31 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:31,621 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_INCLUDE=/app/nginx-app.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + NGINX_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx-app.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:33 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:34,258 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:34,258 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:34,261 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:34,261 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/nginx.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_FPM_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/php-fpm.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php-fpm.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + PHP_INI_OVERRIDE=/app/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/php.ini ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + mv /app/php.ini /opt/php/lib/conf.d
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_ADDITION=/app/additional-supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n '' ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + SUPERVISORD_CONF_OVERRIDE=/app/supervisord.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/additional-supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -f /app/supervisord.conf ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 172.17.0.3 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -n 11211 ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + cat
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + cat
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + '[' -z appweb ']'
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + sed -i 's|%%DOC_ROOT%%|appweb|g' /opt/php/lib/php.ini
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  + exec /usr/bin/supervisord
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 09:23:34 default[20160709t041818]    'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-09 09:23:35 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:35,263 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 13
2016-07-09 09:23:35 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:35,272 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 14
2016-07-09 09:23:35 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:35,279 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 15
2016-07-09 09:23:36 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:36,422 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:23:36 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:36,422 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:23:36 default[20160709t041818]  2016-07-09 09:23:36,422 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,403 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,406 INFO waiting for cron, nginx, php-fpm to die
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,406 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,409 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,095 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,096 INFO waiting for cron, nginx, php-fpm to die
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,096 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2016-07-09 09:24:42 default[20160709t034615]  2016-07-09 09:24:42,099 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
```

Please forgive the enormous block of code, but I don't know what's important in it. My understanding is that with a basic cloud app, credentials are not a big thing. Any idea why I'm getting the 404 Not Found / nginx error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error message once or twice while writing an app based on the same tutorial series, though I'm using Node.js.

For me, my app appeared to have been crashing because of exceptions (which I fixed in a few cases), and also what appears to be a problem with connect-memcache (that one I'm still trying to debug...).

I figured out this much by commenting out huge sections of code, making an extremely simple page that I would be sure would show up, then gradually un-commenting code and re-deploying to see if that uncommented code broke anything.